# GeoPandas: Apply function to row multiple time

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame with the following columns. The column *node_location* is a dictionary of OSM node IDs with the corresponding coordinates.

```
{
    "geometry": LineString(LINESTRING (8.6320625 49.3500941, 8.632062 49.3501782)),
    "node_locations": {75539413: {"lat": 52.5749342, "lon": 13.3008981},
                       75539407: {"lat": 52.5746156, "lon": 13.3029441},
                       75539412: {"lat": 52.5751579, "lon": 13.3012622}
    ...
}
```

My goal is to split all intersecting lines, but **only** if the intersection point exists in the *node_locations* columns. E.g. in the picture only the lines with the green dot should be splitted, because the green dot is a point in the node_locations. The red one does not appear there, so it should not be splitted.

As I have a lot of data, I want to use *apply()* to make it more performant. I created a function *split_intersecting_ways* that iterates over each row and and determines all intersecting geometries. Then I use another apply that calls *split_intersecting_geometries* on all these intersecting rows and pass my row from the first apply function as argument to split the geometry. This new split geometry should be used in the next iteration. As I can have multiple intersecting geometries where I should split, it should split the original geometry iterative and use the previus splitted GeometryCollection as input for the new iteration.

```
def split_intersecting_geometries(intersecting, row):
    if intersecting.name != row.name and intersecting.geometry.type != 'GeometryCollection':
        intersection = row.geometry.intersection(intersecting.geometry)
        if intersection.type == 'Point':
            lon, lat = intersection.coords.xy
            for key, value in row.node_locations.items():
                if lat[0] == value["lat"] and lon[0] == value["lon"]:
                    return split(row.geometry, intersecting.geometry) # Creates a GeometryCollection with splitted lines
    return row.geometry

def split_intersecting_ways(row, data):
    intersecting_rows = data[data.geometry.intersects(row.geometry)]
    data['geometry'] = intersecting_rows.apply(split_intersecting_geometries, args=(row,), axis=1)
    return data['geometry']

edges['geometry'] = edges.apply(split_intersecting_ways, args=(edges,), axis=1)
```

After some iterations I get the error **Columns must be same length as key**. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Your geometry column is bot correct